# Way to query and update data in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I run a payment system with Stripe and am trying to decrement a quantity field in Firestore after every successful purchase. I can get the document but I'm struggling figuring out how to update it.

```
db.collection('products').where('id', '==', dbRef).get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
        return querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            return res.json({
                data: doc.data(),
                err: err
            })
        })
    })
```

```
{
  "data": {
    "stripe": {
      "sku": "sku_xxx",
      "product": "prod_xxx"
    },
    "name": "VERSA HOODIE",
    "id": "pmz0pvfa",
    "createdBy": "Q3Vn0LLRnSWzxaeOK7V0UYbuiKF2",
    "price": "25.00",
    "quantity": 10,
    "inStock": true,
    "description": "TEST PRODUCT",
    "imageURL": "https://xxx"
  },
  "err": null
}
```

I tried stuff like `doc.update({})`, but it doens't work...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(If your query always returns one and only one document, see below)*

---

To update all the documents returned by a query, you need to call the [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update) method of the [`DocumentReference`s](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference), as follows:

```
db.collection('products').where('id', '==', dbRef).get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            const docRef = doc.ref;
            docRef.update({...});
        })
    })
```

If you want to know when all the updates are done, and possibly add to the promise chain another call to an asynchronous method, you should use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) as follows:

```
db.collection('products').where('id', '==', dbRef).get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
        const promises = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            const docRef = doc.ref;
            promises.push(docRef.update({...}));
        })
        return Promise.all(promises);
    })
    .then(...)
```

---

Note that if you are sure you have less than 500 updates to be done, you could use a set of [batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions?authuser=0#batched-writes).

---

**If you know that there is only ONE document corresponding to the query**, just do as follows:

```
db.collection('products').where('id', '==', dbRef).get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
        const docRef = querySnapshot.docs[0].ref;
        return docRef.update({...});
    })
```

---

Finally, note that if you want to increment or decrement a field in Firestore, you should use [`FieldValue.increment()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#static-increment)

Comment: One question, I tried `quantity: admin.firestore().FieldValue.increment(-1)`. I had a look at the documention but it wasn't very clear. Is this correct?

Comment: It depends: are you using the admin SDK or a client SDK?

Comment: I'm using the admin SDK

Comment: If you are using the Admin SDK, do as follows: `const FieldValue = require('firebase-admin').firestore.FieldValue; ... quantity: FieldValue.increment(-1);`