# How to use where and update

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to do this:

```
database.collection('UsuariosDev').where('Telefono', '==', textInput.current.value)
    .update({
        citas: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(database.doc('NegociosDev/Peluquerías/Negocios/PR01/citas/' + docRef.id))
})
```

Get the doc from the collection "UsuariosDev" where "Telefono" equals "textInput.current.value", and then update it. But it seems like I can't use "update" next to "where". Any ideas?

Comment: is this react related?

Comment: Well, it's web, I don't know if firebase use the same code between platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Firestore doesn't support update queries. To update a document you need to know its full path. So to update all documents matching a query, you'll need to:

1. Execute that query against the database
2. Loop over the resulting documents
3. Update each document in turn

Also see:

- [Way to query and update data in Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61729245/way-to-query-and-update-data-in-firestore)
- [update cloud firestore document without id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54541228/update-cloud-firestore-document-without-id/54542410#54542410)