# How do I modify only null values in a Firestore document without querying initial state?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

In Firestore, I have documents that have fields that may or may not be null. If there are indeed holding a `null` value, I'd like to write on them. If not, I don't want to write to them.

Is there a way to do this **without** checking it before updating it?

---

*Note: I am operating on Firebase Cloud Functions.*

Answer (score 0):

Good idea to use FireStore Rule Condition for write (update) action.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions

Try to set SKIP if field exist

Answer (score -1):

Writing to a document requires that you know its full path. And the only way to know the full paths of the documents with the relevant value is to perform a query for those documents. So no, there's no way to update all documents that meet a specific condition without first querying for them, and thus incurring the read cost.

Also see:

- [Can Firestore update multiple documents matching a condition, using one query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48947499/can-firestore-update-multiple-documents-matching-a-condition-using-one-query)
- [update cloud firestore document without id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54541228/update-cloud-firestore-document-without-id/54542410#54542410)
- [Way to query and update data in Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61729245/way-to-query-and-update-data-in-firestore)

Comment: I think the question was not about updating every document with null value in them but more only updating a value if the value is null.